# Skobbler advice issues

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, skmaps

I have been playing with the [Skobbler SDK](http://www.skobbler.com/) demo app. I am particularly interested in the SKRouteAdvice where it essentially advises you to turn left and such. 
The problem I have encountered with the Swift demo is that it seems to give you the entire array of advice right at the very start before the trip even begins and doesnt pan it out across as the trip happens.

Anyone else encounter this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive the advices during the navigation by listening to the [SKNavigationDelegate](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.5.1/Protocols/SKNavigationDelegate.html) callbacks.

See the Swift examples [here](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec21).

Comment: For reference I was speaking about  this example http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec19